# Is it possible to search all columns through MySQL table in PHP query, without typing out each column name?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I am asking this because I am looking for a PHP query for MySQL like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ALL_COLUMNS LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
```

Does a query like this exist? Or do I have to type the query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
    user_email LIKE '%" . $search. "%'
    OR user_name LIKE '%" . $search. "%'
    OR first_name LIKE '%" . $search. "%' OR [...]
```

Comment: Just fyi, this will most likely murder your performance as the table size increases.

Comment: I think it would be a useful query where it would have to be used in multiple tables with moderate table sizes.

Comment: I'm relatively sure that what you're looking for doesnt exist. Its usefulness would be limited to a select few edge cases and it's not a very good idea to run something like this in production anyways. You could have PHP generate the sql query for you and go that route. That said, I'm not a DBA.

Comment: It might be better to have an amalgamated field with all of this data in it, and then add a `FULLTEXT` index to it. [See here for more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can probably achieve something like this in your favorite `mysql` frontend, I use sqlyog and you can do that with the "data search" tool, I'm sure other software like mysql workbench has a similar option.

Anyway, you can have php construct the query for you. Get all of the columns into an array by querying `information_schema`, and then make a string with each columns name like

```
"columnName LIKE '%$search%'"
```

and then `implode` it on `" OR "`, like this:

```
//what is the search?
$search = "something";
//get all the columns

    $columns = mysqli_query("SELECT 
  COLUMN_NAME 
FROM
  information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' 
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDatabaseName' ");

//put each like clause in an array
$queryLikes = array();
while ($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($columns)) {
    $queryLikes[] = $column['COLUMN_NAME'] . " LIKE '%$search%'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $queryLikes);
echo $query; //should look like this:
//SELECT * FROM users WHERE column1 LIKE '%something%' OR column2 LIKE '%something%' OR column3 LIKE '%something%' OR ...
//so then
$users=mysqli_query($query);
while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    //do stuff with $user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:
Just iterate through all columns in your table and check them for the value you want.

This example searches column titled "column"

```
$qry= mysql_query("select * from $tblName order by id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    if($searchItem == $row['column']){
        echo "Match found!";
        break;
    }
}
```